# Searching all the existance of particular file with Batch

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file, cmd

am struggling through these crewl batch cmds from quite long.

I need to search file (actually the installation folder of some software (XYZ) (I know there is a way to check that in registry
but I wanted an easy way to check some ABC.cmd file; if that exist give me the path of that file;

but the problem is that file also exist at various places and giving me the wrong answer.

Can some body please tell me so It can give me all file existence in least time and then I could select which I want to select with batch script.

this is my current code but It's giving the first one which it found and not my desired one:

```
@echo  off 
FOR /f "Tokens=*" %%i in ('DIR \stDesign.cmd /B /S /a-d') do (set PATH="%%~dpi")
FOR /f "Tokens=*" %%i in ('DIR \stDesign.cmd /od /b /S') do (set URL="%%~dpi")
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first `/a-d` and `/od` are not switches for `dir`. I believe that you meant `/a:d` and `/o:d` respectively.

Apart from those errors the reason your first `for` statement doesn't work is because `DIR \stDesign.cmd /B /S /a:d` is searching for ***directories**** called `stDesign.cmd`, not files.

Your second `for` statement is telling `DIR` to order the files by their creation date, but that only works for files inside the same directories, not across directories. Meaning that any matching files inside the same directory will be sorted by date, but files that exist inside seprate directories will be in the ordered that `DIR` found them.

Try

```
@echo off
  echo.
  REM Housekeeping: Delete any existing files left-over from previous runs
  if exist "%tmp%\~.tm?" del "%tmp%\~.tm?"

  REM Find the files
  for %%v in (*.bat) do (

    REM Extract Date, Time, Path, File Name, and Extention
    for /f "tokens=1-3* delims=/ " %%w in ("%%~tdpnxv") do ( 

      REM Change the date around so that simply sorting the lines
      REM will order them by date and time.
      echo %%y/%%w/%%x %%z>>%tmp%\~.tmp
    )
  )

  REM Sort (in ascending order) and Display data
  type "%tmp%\~.tmp" | sort

  REM Housekeeping
  del "%tmp%\~.tmp"

echo.
```

REM Or, if you don't want to display the time and date, replace the type line with:

```
@echo off
  echo.
  REM Housekeeping: Delete any existing files left-over from previous runs
  if exist "%tmp%\~.tm?" del "%tmp%\~.tm?"

  REM Find the files
  for %%v in (*.bat) do (

    REM Extract Date, Time, Path, File Name, and Extention
    for /f "tokens=1-3* delims=/ " %%w in ("%%~tdpnxv") do ( 

      REM Change the date around so that simply sorting the lines
      REM will order them by date and time.
      echo %%y/%%w/%%x %%z>>%tmp%\~.tmp
    )
  )

  REM Sort (in ascending order) and save data to ~.tm2
  type "%tmp%\~.tmp" | sort >> "%tmp%\~.tm2"

  REM Extract path and file name only from ~.tm2 and display it
  for /f "tokens=4* usebackq" %%x in ("%tmp%\~.tm2") do echo %%x


  REM Housekeeping
  del "%tmp%\~.tmp"

echo.
```

The first example gives an output like this:

```
1992\01\15 00:12:55 C:\SOMEPATH\FILE0001.EXT
2004\04\17 00:42:17 C:\ANOTHERPATH\FILE0002.EXT
2004\04\17 12:42:17 C:\MISCPATH\RANDOM\FILE0003.EXT
2012\10\15 00:12:55 C:\EXAMPLE\FILE0004.EXT
2012\01\15 00:12:55 C:\FILE0005.EXT
```

The 2nd example displays only the path and file names, but still ordered by date + time.

```
C:\SOMEPATH\FILE0001.EXT
C:\ANOTHERPATH\FILE0002.EXT
C:\MISCPATH\RANDOM\FILE0003.EXT
C:\EXAMPLE\FILE0004.EXT
C:\FILE0005.EXT
```

To reverse the sort order, use the /R switch with `sort`, like so:

```
type tmp.txt | sort /R
```

*Directories and Folders are the same thing.

Comment: thanks very much for your efforts and explaination really appreciated; I need the path of all existing files and wanted to select one of them :-)

Comment: I goofed when I gave the output, it does include the path. I'll update my answer now.

Comment: It would be simple enough to print line numbers along with each path and file name so that you could then use `set /p choice=Enter a line number to select: ` Is that the sort of thing you are looking for?

Comment: yes I want the user can select from the above given results. Can you tell please what is your search spectrum where are you searching in whole C:\ or current directory or on whole computer?.

Comment: Actually, I gave you edited results. That's why the directory names were 'somepath' and 'random'. When I tested it I actually was searching f:\music and it's sub-directories (of which there are many) for *.bat files I'd strewn around. Do you want me to edit my answer to include line numbers and a selection method?

Comment: I meant to ask you that in code where are you telling that in that directory you search or it's searching by default in the current directory from where the script is running or where batch script resides and forwards or it select the whole drive like F:\